# HKActivitySummary is nil in the morning

Tags: ios, healthkit

I'm making an app that uses your `HKActivitySummary`. One thing I've noticed is that in the morning, before I do any activity, I get a `nil` value back from `HKQuery.predicateForActivitySummary()`.

Once I earn a single active calorie, I start getting non-nil values back as you'd expect.

Here's the query:

```
let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
let components = Set<Calendar.Component>([.day, .month, .year, .era])
var dateComponents = calendar.dateComponents(components, from: Date())
dateComponents.calendar = calendar
let todayPredicate = HKQuery.predicateForActivitySummary(with: dateComponents)
let query = HKActivitySummaryQuery(predicate: todayPredicate) { query, summaries, error in
    // If I haven't moved yet today, summaries is an empty array,
    // and the error is nil.
    // However, if I've moved a bit, summaries is non-empty!
    // Is there a way to adjust this query to avoid the nil-in-the-morning issue?
}
store.execute(query)
```

Is there a way to avoid this issue with `HKQuery`?

**UPDATE:** I’ve filed a radar with Apple; if you’d like to duplicate it, the number is 36026782.

Comment: Please include the relevant snippet of code. When you say you get nil back, do you mean the NSPredicate returned from HKQuery. HKQuery.predicateForActivitySummary() is nil, or are the result passed to your HKActivitySummaryQuery's results handler nil?

Comment: @Allan Ah right, sorry! I've added the code sample, and a description of what I'm seeing in the HKActivitySummaryQuery's results handler.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug you should [file with Apple](https://bugreport.apple.com). However, it seems like the workaround is straightforward: if you get an empty array back then you can consider it the same as getting an `HKActivitySummary` with zeros for all values, which is what you'd get if the bug were fixed.

Comment: Yes, though: there's more information in HKActivitySummary than just zeroes - there's the current-day's Move goal! My current plan is to fill that in with *yesterday's* Move Goal, but it's possible that that would be inaccurate if the user had just changed their Move goal.